# Run a Job in Background

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I need a block of code which run a job in background. Suppose the user click on the Submit button, then a job starts in background, in the mean time the user closes that window and run a different job, and the job should keep running.

Please provide some help in ASP.NET and VB.NET.

Thank You Very Much For Your Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) method which allows you to run some some method on a thread drawn from the thread pool. As an alternative you could use the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class to spawn a new thread manually if it is a long running task to avoid jeopardizing a thread from the pool which contains a limited number of threads and which are also used to service requests in ASP.NET applications.

Comment: But what happens when the session terminates, if it's a long running job. Doesn't the threads go down with it?

Comment: @ Patrick, no, threads are not related to the session. They are related to the AppDomain, so as long as IIS keeps the application loaded they will run. If on the other hand IIS unloads the application pool, threads will stop running as well.

Comment: So starting a thread might not solve this depending on the lifetime of the job being executed? Do you know how long does it take before the application gets taken down by IIS?

Comment: Since you have no direct control over the lifetime of the web application, a background thread is generally a bad idea. If the job is short and sweet, and you can live with a chance of it being killed before completing, without losing data, then sure, but otherwise I would implement the job in a service and somehow communicate to that service that a new job is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating a windows service that host a wcf service, when the user click on the submit button you can send the request to the windows service and the windows service will run in the background event the user closes the window.

Answer (score 1):

A [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) may be the easiest place to start. Put your code in the DoWork event.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), depending on your context.

Answer (score 0):

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) will run in the background and can be easily used to sync back updates to your GUI if needed.

Or use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)...